# Correcting angles between two points in Python

Tags: python, trigonometry

I have a python code application that is recording mouse activity (points recorded at regular intervals, timeWait) and then processes the data to output the angle that the mouse has moved (with the Y axis being 0) and the speed that it has moved at.

At the moment my output is providing East as 0°, South as -90°, West as 180° and North as 90°, which is not my expected output. I am not sure if there is something wrong in the trigonometry or in the other calculations, so any help on any part of this would be appreciated.

```
i = 0
angles = []
speeds = []

#positions is an array of coordinates taken 0.1 seconds apart from each other

for point in positions:
    if i is not 0:
        pointY = 2500 - point[1]  #invert position of X and assign variable
        deltaX = point[0]-pointXP # difference is current pointX minus PointXPast
        deltaY = pointY-pointYP
        dist = math.sqrt(deltaX**2 + deltaY**2) #distance is the hypotenuse
        if dist is 0: #if the mouse has not moved
            continue
        speed = dist/timeWait # speed is distance/time
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX)) #angle using Tan

        angles.append(angle)
        speeds.append(speed)

        pointXP = point[0]
        pointYP = pointY

    else:  #this is only for the first iteration
        i = 1 
        pointXP = point[0]
        pointYP = 2500 - point[1]
        continue
```

Again, any help is appreciated especially regarding my angles being off. Thanks.

Comment: How do you get the mouse position without any module? Or you just post a piece of the code? Could you please post the entire code?

Comment: What _is_ your expected output?

Comment: The mouse positions are taken at regular intervals using the mouse package and leaves me with an array of X and Y values.

Comment: My outputs are the array of speeds, and an array of directions that the mouse went in. I will share more code later when I get back home. The two arrays then go into 'windrose' to visualise the data.

Comment: And, what do you expect to be the output from a horizontal rightwards movement like `atan2(0,1)`? Now try it, see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `math.atan2` to compute the angle.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2),

> The vector in the plane from the origin to point (x, y) makes this angle with the positive X axis.

If you want the angle to be relative to the positive Y axis, you can subtract 90 degrees from the angle. (ie. `angles.append(angle - 90)`)

Comment: Would this work as I am hoping if I input the variables the other way round to find the angle? e.g. math.atan2(detlaY,deltaX) ?

Comment: changing the variables fixed it... D'oh! Thanks for making me think of it! I then used 
```
angle=+360
```
on anything less than 0 to get values from 0-360. cheers again

Comment: Very nice, glad I could help